"when" plus present simple and continuous

When you are opening a beer, do it quietly - in other words don't make noise while opening your beer

When you open a beer, do it quietly -  I think it is understable with the same meaning as 1 but not natural, simply, it is unidiomatic.


So, if we discuss some actions  that are quickly performed like in my example or others such as "throw" and we want to discuss  how to act while the short action is performed, is it good to use present continuouus to make the meaning clear whereas simple would be not good English?

No, both tenses would be equally acceptable.

@KateBunting "Whenever I open the beer she gets angry vs whenever I am opening the beer she gets angry".  Is here the difference? Either after I open or during opening?

If she gets angry because you are opening/have just opened another can/bottle of beer, the tense doesn't affect the meaning.

@KateBunting right but there might be slight shift either emhpasising the completion or process?

The determining factor is not the relative quickness of the action. Rather,  it's whether the verb's action is understood to occur in an instant or as a process that requires time, one that has duration.  Consider the difference:  trip over your shoelace vs. sing that song.  We can say "I was singing that song when she arrived" but not "I was tripping over my shoelace when she arrived".  A trip occurs instantaneously.  "to open something" is a process with duration, even if some things can be opened much more quickly than other things.

[lots of spelling, punctuation and grammar issues corrected] Better to use a computer than a smartphone here.

I didn't have time to pursue this topic yesterday.  The point is that when you open refers to the event, when you are opening to the process. Any noise happens during the process, but someone being angry (presumably because they think you are drinking too much) can either be during or after the opening. In the latter case the simple present would be more idiomatic.

@KateBunting I think there might the differnce if we talk about something that happend only once in the past for instance "when I jumped/was jumping my trainer gave me tips how to improve my performace" Simple past = after jump and continuou = during jumping. On the other hand when we talk about something repated there is no difference between tenes? "Whenever I jump/ i am jumpin my trainers give me tips ....". In both example during jumping?

If you only made one jump, it's unlikely that the trainer would give advice while you were doing it. 'When/while I was jumping...' could imply that you made several jumps in one training session and received advice between jumps.

@KateBunting "Whenever I jump he gives me advice" could imply more than one jump each time, right?

Possibly it could.

@KateBunting On the other hand if we mean only one instace in the past not repeated" yesterday when I jumped he gave me advice how to improve my technique' rather means after one jump, correct?

"When I jumped" and "Whenever I jump" would normally imply one jump, though, as I said, a session of jumping could possibly be meant.
